# print keys and values of hash next to each other

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash that looks like this

```
my %results = (
    'Ende Deaktiviere PKonten' => [
                                      '31.05.2018 03:28:33',
                                      '01.06.2018 03:54:18',
    ],
    'Ende Monatswechsel P-Konten' => [
                                         '31.05.2018 03:34:24',
                                         '01.06.2018 04:29:05',
    ]
);
```

I would like to print it in this format:

```
'Ende Deaktiviere PKonten' 'Ende Monatswechsel P-Konten' 
'31.05.2018 03:28:33'       '31.05.2018 03:34:24'
'01.06.2018 03:54:18'       '01.06.2018 04:29:05'
```

Can someone help me on how to do this?

I tried this:

```
foreach my $key (keys %results) {
            $N = scalar @{ $results{$key} };

            for my $i (0..($N-1)) {
                    print "i= $i , @{ $results{$key} }[$i]" ;
                    print "\n";
            }
print "\t";
}
```

Output

`31.05.2018 03:37:47
01.06.2018 04:53:44
02.06.2018 03:37:14
07.06.2018 03:21:04
08.06.2018 03:40:04
31.05.2018 03:37:30
01.06.2018 04:53:23
02.06.2018 03:36:58
07.06.2018 03:20:51
08.06.2018 03:39:51`

Comment: @Unsal: So what kind of answer are you expecting? I'm not alone in this; many people, perhaps the majority, frown on questions that contain just *"How can I do this"* with no code at all. Knowing no Perl is solved by *learning it*,  not getting others to do your work. But this problem isn't unique to Perl: solve it it your preferred language and port it.

Comment: So what kind of answer are you expecting? a hint, not a served solution

Comment: Hint: build the columns as rows and transpose the matrix.

Comment: @Andrey foreach my $key (sort keys %results) {
        push @$a, join("\n",split(/\|/,join('|',@{$results{$key}})));
}

Comment: `split( /\|/, join( '|', @{$results{$key}} ) )` is the same as `@{$results{$key}}` unless there are already pipe characters in the array elements.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want. You first print keys, and then print array one value at a time from each array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash = {
    'Ende Deaktiviere PKonten' => [
        '31.05.2018 03:28:33',
        '01.06.2018 03:54:18',
    ],
    'Ende Monatswechsel P-Konten' => [
        '31.05.2018 03:34:24',
        '01.06.2018 04:29:05',
    ]
};
my $arrLingth = @{$hash->{(keys %$hash)[0]}};
foreach my $key(keys %$hash) {
    printf "%25s", $key . "\t";
}
print "\n";
for(my $i=0; $i<$arrLingth; $i++) {
    foreach my $key(keys %$hash) {
        printf "%25s", $hash->{$key}->[$i] . "\t";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This builds an array of column information and transposes it as it is printed. Much of the code is involved with generalising the `printf` format, and it could be very much shorter

Note that the columns will be in no particular order because hashes are inherently *unordered* by design

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'max';

my %results = (
    'Ende Deaktiviere PKonten'    => [ '31.05.2018 03:28:33', '01.06.2018 03:54:18' ],
    'Ende Monatswechsel P-Konten' => [ '31.05.2018 03:34:24', '01.06.2018 04:29:05' ],
);

{
    my @columns = map [ $_, @{ $results{$_} } ], keys %results;

    my $w    = max map length, map @$_, @columns;
    my $imax = max map $#$_, @columns;
    my $fmt  = join(' ', ("%-${w}s") x @columns) . "\n";

    for my $i ( 0 .. $imax ) {
        printf $fmt, map $_->[$i] // '', @columns;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ende Monatswechsel P-Konten Ende Deaktiviere PKonten   
31.05.2018 03:34:24         31.05.2018 03:28:33        
01.06.2018 04:29:05         01.06.2018 03:54:18
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
say join "\t", map {"'$_'"} keys %results;

my $N = scalar @{ $results{ (keys %results)[0] } };
for my $i (0..($N - 1)) {
    my @row;
    for ( keys %results ) {
        push @row, $results{$_}[$i];
    }
    say join "\t", map {"'$_'"} @row;
}
```